ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageDataGenerator' from 'tensorflow.keras.preprocessing'
Problem when importing the ImageDataGenerator from keras.
I tried using:
from tensorflow import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import ImageDataGenerator

Creating alias for keras and/or tensorflow, no success.
Receiving the following Error Message:
File "/Users/<mine>/<mine>/<mine>/<mine>/training/zz_train.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import ImageDataGenerator
ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageDataGenerator' from 'tensorflow.keras.preprocessing' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/_tf_keras/keras/preprocessing/__init__.py)


Try this:
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

or
from keras.src.legacy.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

this is depcrecated as well :
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator
"Deprecated: tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator is not recommended for new code. Prefer loading images with tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory and transforming the output"

Upgrade TensorFlow to a compatible version.
